# How to add Public IP to Cent OS

Tags: ssh, centos, networkmanager

I am trying to configure a Public(Static) IP in Cent OS 6.4. For this, I made a copy of eth0(added local IP, so that I can connect the system to Internet) and named it to eth0:0(added Public IP, so that the system can be accessible via SSH).

After restarting the network devices, am still not able to get the required result.

I want to access this system via SSH with the configured public IP.

Comment: Does your eth0 is already "facing" the Lan interface of  your modem/router that is directly connected to the internet? The way you asked it seems that you added a secondary ip on a interface that is inside your network.

Comment: Yes! eth0 is connect to Internet and added Public IP to eth0:0. Have to configure it on single Ethernet card.

Comment: Don't the DNS of ISP has to know your IP(public) for routing incoming packets?